# Multiple raster processing with SetNull?

Tags: arcpy, raster, modelbuilder

I have two folders containing 5 raster files in each.

- FolderA="a,b,c,d,e"
- FolderB="f,g,h,i,j"

All files are in .tiff format.

The raster datasets in Folder A have valid range from -1 to 1 and those in Folder B have valid range from 0 to 3. What I am trying to do is mask each file in Folder A with files in Folder B (Mask File a.tiff with f.tiff, b.tiff with g.tiff and so on).

I am trying to achieve this with raster iterator and SetNull from spatial analyst with files in folder B as conditional rasters, files in folder A as constant and expression "VALUE">1.

My model looks something like this:

[image]

The ModelBuilder won't let me use iterate raster more than once. Creating a submodel for iterate raster won't run each tool in the model for each iterated value (which is basically what I want to do). I also tried this in python script but couldn't achieve the desired output:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace=r"E:\A"
alist=arcpy.ListRasters()
arcpy.env.workspace=r"E:\B"
blist=arcpy.ListRasters()
for i in range(len(alist)):
    outras=arcpy.sa.SetNull(blist[i]>1,alist[i])
    outras.save("E:\\"+i+"_Mask.tif")
```

Comment: Try `outras=arcpy.sa.SetNull(blist[i], alist[i], "Value > 1")`.

Comment: In model builder, you need both rasters to be in the same loop and sub-model approach with independent iterators may not work. I suggest using Calculate Value to form your raster lists (as in your python code) and use `For` iterator on the enumerated raster paths.